# Internal speakers do not work on an Asus A3Ac

Tags: sound, 12.10, asus, headphones, speakers

I have a new *(from scratch, not update)* installation of Ubuntu 12.10 on my notebook, **Asus A3Ac** *(It is based on Intel Centrino - Pentium M with full duplex Intel HDA codec)*.

In older versions of Debian-based systems Intel HDA audio didn't work correctly. Alsamixer display wrong outputs and inputs *(more than notebook really have)*. In clean installations internal speakers were playing, but they didn't mute when headphones was plugged in.
There was a solution *(propably not the best but working)* - edit as root /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and add a line "options snd-hda-intel model=z71v position_fix=1". After restart it worked correctly *(alsamixer displayed correct devices and internal speakers were muted after I plugged in headphones)*. It was also working in Ubuntu 12.04.

**In Ubuntu 12.10 I have another problem. The alsamixer in default** *(don't have to edit alsa-base.conf)* **display correct outputs and inputs but internal speakers don't working if the headphones isn't plugged in.** I have to manually disable "Auto-Mut" option in alsamixer, then the internal spakers works *(but of course they don't mute when the headphones are pluged in)*.

Thanks for any idea how to fix it. I'm not sure if it is a bug or it's caused by a "specific hardware".

Tomas

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue,

type alsamixer in terminal, navigate left to Auto-Mut and set it disable

@edit:
sorry, just saw that you mentioned this already :D